# How to plug TS 6.5 mic to laptop

Tags: microphone, old, adapters

I found this pretty old microphone and I wanted to see if there were any chances of using it. It is a DM-30 Dynamic Microphone from Pioneer Electronic Corp.

I tried using a 6.5 to 3.5 adapter to my laptop but it still isn't working. PLus it came with this weird blue and orange wire that I dont know what it is for. How can I plug it in so I can use it? It's more of a novelty really

Weird cable: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j46rO.jpg)

Microphone box and jack: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/juZe2.jpg)

Plus, it came with no instruction manual

Comment: While Graham has given this a useful answer, this is not on topic for Sound Design so I'll close.

Answer (score 1):

The "weird cable" looks like an FM radio antenna, which corresponds with the hand-written note on the microphone box. The spade terminals will fit onto screws on the tuner/receiver it was intended for.

The dynamic microphone will produce a lower output level than the internally amplified electret ("condenser") microphones usually used with PCs. If you set the input/recording levels to maximum sensitivity in any software you're using (including the sound app in control panel) you may be able to hear something.

If you can hear a faint signal you could use a microphone pre-amp or external sound card to boost the level. But if you don't already have one lying around it wouldn't be worth buying one just to use an elderly microphone of average quality; you'd be better off buying a modern cheap condenser (i.e. electret) mic intended for use with a PC, with either a 3.5 mm audio plug or a USB interface.